# Number of intersections in the first quadrant.

Tags: functions

Let $f,g:\mathbb {R}_{+}\longrightarrow \mathbb {R}_{+}$ be strictly decreasing functions. Is it possible that their graphs do not intersect? ($\mathbb {R}_{+}$ means positive real numbers) I feel like it's not possible but don't know how to prove it.

Comment: $g=f+1$ should answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try $y=1/x$ and y=2/x$

They are decreasing and they do not intersect